# Why does removing "export" keyword cause TypeScript error "Cannot find name 'artificialLatency'." to disappear?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm not sure whether I am misunderstanding something here or it is a TypeScript / VSCode bug... why am I not always getting the error shown in `example.ts` when I use `artificialLatency` without importing it?

I expect to see the error regardless of whether I export it or not, since I'm never importing it, but the error disappears when I delete `export`.

[image]
[image]

I am using the default `react-ts` Vite template

`example.ts`

```
const myOtherVar = artificialLatency;
console.log(myOtherVar);
```

`example2.ts`

```
export const artificialLatency = 2000;
console.log(artificialLatency);
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

`tsconfig.node.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "include": ["vite.config.ts"]
}
```

Comment: See the compiler option [`moduleDetection`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#moduleDetection). TypeScript treats identifier references differently depending on whether it infers the file to be a [module or classic script](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules/theory.html#scripts-and-modules-in-javascript). If this answers your question, I can write it as one. If not, what am I missing?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77592392/why-does-removing-export-keyword-cause-typescript-error-cannot-find-name-myv#comment136791306_77592392) Either way, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77592392/edit) the question to include a [mre] and post [actual code and error messages as text instead of as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/438273). See [ask].

Comment: I've edited my question to be an MRE. I initially struggled to reproduce it because the problem depended not only on my code but the project config. Adding `"moduleDetection": "force"` did resolve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Historically, TypeScript used the presence of `import` and `export` statements as a heuristic for determining whether a file should be checked as a [module instead of a classic script](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules/theory.html#scripts-and-modules-in-javascript).

There is a compiler option [`moduleDetection`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#moduleDetection) which can be configured to control this behavior:

> This setting controls how TypeScript determines whether a file is a [script or a module](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules/theory.html#scripts-and-modules-in-javascript).
>
> There are three choices:
>
> - `"auto"` (default) - TypeScript will not only look for import and export statements, but it will also check whether the `"type"` field in a `package.json` is set to `"module"` when running with [module](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#module): `nodenext` or `node16`, and check whether the current file is a JSX file when running under [jsx](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#jsx): `react-jsx`.
> - `"legacy"` - The same behavior as 4.6 and prior, usings import and export statements to determine whether a file is a module.
> - `"force"` - Ensures that every non-declaration file is treated as a module.

Answer (score 1):

When a JavaScript or TypeScript file does not contain any `import` or `export` keywords, it is not a module and the variables such as `artificialLatency` may end up on the global scope so the code may work (for example if `artificialLatency.ts` is compiled to `artificialLatency.js` and added to a Web page via a `<script>` tag).

The best thing to do is to ensure all files that are supposed to be modules contain at least one `import` or `export` keyword.